# jQuery, ajax wont cache

Tags: jquery, ajax, browser-cache

Why will my jQuery ajax not support the [ETag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag) feature?

You see in the second example, there is no "If-None-Match" header. But why?

In both tested browser i have a 50% change to have a cache will pressing F5 but in simply reopen the page by clicking links it wont work.

**Working none jQuery example**

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        console.log( xmlhttp.responseText );
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","/energyManagerSensor/getCleanData/sensor_id/4?shrink_type=day&from=18.11.2011&to=23.02.2013",true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

REQUEST Header

```
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de-CH;q=0.6,fr-FR;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4,en-gb;q=0.3,sr-RS;q=0.2,sr;q=0.1
Cache-Control   max-age=0
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  PHPSESSID=iie173rsc5bqggll6uhmg6m7i6
Host    sfportal3_hh_dev
If-Modified-Since   Tue, 12 Feb 2013 0:0:0 GMT
If-None-Match   4SdayF1321570800T1361574000
Referer http://sfportal3_hh_dev/energyManagerDisplay/view/display_id/1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 FirePHP/0.7.1
x-insight   activate
```

RESPONSE Header

```
Cache-Control   max-age=3600
Connection  close
Date    Tue, 12 Feb 2013 06:16:23 GMT
Expires Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
```

**NOT Working jQuery example**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/energyManagerSensor/getCleanData/sensor_id/4?shrink_type=day&from=18.11.2011&to=23.02.2013",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    ifModified: true,
    success: function(return_data) {
    console.log(return_data);
    }
});
```

REQUEST Header

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,de-CH;q=0.6,fr-FR;q=0.5,fr;q=0.4,en-gb;q=0.3,sr-RS;q=0.2,sr;q=0.1
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  PHPSESSID=iie173rsc5bqggll6uhmg6m7i6
Host    sfportal3_hh_dev
Referer http://sfportal3_hh_dev/energyManagerDisplay/view/display_id/1
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:18.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/18.0 FirePHP/0.7.1
X-Requested-With    XMLHttpRequest
x-insight   activate
```

RESPONSE Header

```
Cache-Control   max-age=3600
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Type    text/json
Date    Tue, 12 Feb 2013 06:18:41 GMT
Etag    5SdayF1321570800T1361574000
Expires Tue, 12 Feb 2013 07:02:18 GMT
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=74
Last-Modified   Tue, 12 Feb 2013 0:0:0 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
X-Powered-By    PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3
```

**Test enviroment**

- Firefox 18.0.2
- Chromium 24.0

Comment: Which browser are you you testing with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:

1.)
The "ifModified" on http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
is absolutely wrong in my eyes.
After reading the jQuery [source code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax.js), I would remove the sentence:

<del>"Allow the request to be successful only if the response has changed since the last request."</del>

And would write something like:
If "ifModified" is true, The lastModified and etag header options will be used, for active caching.

2.) I have had a problem in PHP

It is required to send the ETag always, also in case of 304 response.

```
<?php
// Save performance use ETag system 
// @see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag
$lastmod = gmdate('D, d M Y 0:0:0 \G\M\T', time());
$etag = $sensor_id . 'S' . $shrink_type . 'A' . $alarms . 'F' . $from . 'T' . $to . 'D' . date('Dmy');

$ifmod = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'] == $lastmod : null; 
$iftag = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] == $etag : null; 

header_remove('Pragma');
header_remove('Cache-Control');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:m:i \G\M\T', time() + 3600));
header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');
header('Last-Modified: ' . $lastmod); 
header('ETag: ' . $etag);

if (($ifmod || $iftag) && ($ifmod !== false && $iftag !== false)) { 
    header('HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified'); 
    die();
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding. What was the solution? Weren't you having a jquery problem originally?

Comment: My problem was the documentation of the "ifModified" of jquery.ajax. Cause of a miss understoud of documentation i changed my php code. This option needs to be true to force jQuery touse the provided HTTP ETag headers.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! The key learning to anyone who missed it is: If your server returns a 304 remember to attach a ETag to it, or else jQuery wont use the cached response.